# Item collection or items collection?

Tags: grammatical-number

To indicate "a collection of items," do you say "an item collection" or "items collection"? What's the rule?

A quick comparative Google Books search indicates that the [first form](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22item+collection%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) is more common than the [latter](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22items+collection%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl), but I don't know if I can trust that as a parameter.

Comment: When a noun is used adjectivally like this (*an **item** collection, a **car** radio, an **ELU** question* etc.) it's invariably ***singular***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of clarity, I'd suggest simply stating "a collection of items," However, to answer your question, I am inclined to think that they are both unclear in some sense.

Say I have a collection of phones. If I were to say:

- **"I have a phone collection."**
  It is quite easy to understand, at least colloquially, but we need to understand what this means. In this sentence, **phone** is not a noun, but an adjective. It is describing the collection as a whole, not necessarily the constituents thereof.
- **"I have a phones collection."**
  In this case, we are pluralizing an adjective which is not conventionally done in this scenario.

There are certain scenarios in which the latter would be more correct. For example:

- **"I have a clothes basket."**
  or
  **"I have an arts degree."**
  The plural form is more appropriately used when there is little distinction between generic and specific meanings.